# Getting Error on Visual Studio Code for OmniSharp with .Net6 Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, omnisharp

Hi I normally use Visual Studio to create projects however was advised to try and use VS Code for a .Net6 project

There are some errors I am getting in the compiler

it starts with "C# extension Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details"

And these are the errors

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 10/01/2022, 19:56:35
    Target: d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Reactivities.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\Desktop\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17\.omnisharp\1.37.17\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 13868

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.32002.261 16.11.2 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 17.0.0 - "c:\Users\Desktop\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17\.omnisharp\1.37.17\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.32002.261 16.11.2 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Reactivities.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\API\API.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Application\Application.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Persistence\Persistence.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Domain\Domain.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities' on host 11388.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\API\API.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\API\API.csproj'.
d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\API\API.csproj
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): Error: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.

[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\API\API.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Application\Application.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Application\Application.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Application\Application.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Persistence\Persistence.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Persistence\Persistence.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Persistence\Persistence.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: d:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Domain\Domain.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Domain\Domain.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'd:\DevProjects\Reactivities\Domain\Domain.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: API
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Application
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Persistence
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Domain
Received response for /v2/getcodeactions but could not find request
```

I am not sure why it is occurring, after searching I found out some are saying OmniSharp isn't compatible with .net6

If anyone has any solution please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating VS Code and Omnisharp to the latest versions. If does not help - install VS 2022 and try running VS Code again.

Comment: Hi Guru Stron - so I installed VS 2022 and VSC was already up to date - it seems the error is still continuing

Comment: @CoderLevel0 have you tried restarting you computer?

Comment: I think it has been fixed so before updating to VS 2022 this line was there ```[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.``` now its not there sorry lol should have checked better - thanks For the help

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error today. Solution is .NET Framework 4.7.1 developer pack. For some reason sdk 6.0 requires it. You can use this link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=msbuild-developerpacks

Needs to download :

NET/.NET Core -> Supported versions -> .Net6.0 -> x64, x86 or arm64

.NET Framework -> Supported versions -> .NET Framework 4.7.1 -> Developer Pack