# Can't use .NET 6 with VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, sdk, .net-6.0

I changed .NET version before I used the version 5 and I downloaded yesterday the version 6.
But when I try to use it with VS Code (C# extention) I have the following error message :

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141.5): Error: Current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0. You should either target .NET 5.0 or earlier, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

Of course I uninstalled VS Code and reinstalled, reboot my computer.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Do you have .NET6 installed?

Comment: What is output of `dotnet --list-sdks`? Do you have Visual Studio installed (sometimes [it can be important](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70658514/2501279))? do you have `global.json` in the project?

Comment: My dotnet --list-sdks is :

3.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]


I don't have global.json in my solution



I have Visual Studio 2019 installed, should I update?

Comment: I updated Visual studio to 2022 but it doesn't seems to work on VS and VS Code.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I tried to create a simple webapi project that.

Comment: Have you tried setting "omnisharp.useModernNet": true in your settings.json in VS Code?

Comment: Hello I added "omnisharp.useModernNet": true in the settings.json but it doesn't work. I tried also with "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"